# How to create a RPM build for opensuse 11.2 form netatalk 2.0.5

Tags: linux, rpm, opensuse

Is there someone who knows how to create a RPM from netatalk 2.0.5. Or better has a URL to a RPM? I aske this because so fare I know there are no RPM's for opensuse 11.2 (or suse).

Thankyou,

Ivo Trompert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your own rpm using these instructions:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-rpm1/

At least once you have the env setup creating new pkgs is quite quick.

I believe redhat also have pages on this online.